# D3 + ReactJS network graph hangs the browser indefinitely after continuously updating graph

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph

I am currently learning reactjs and d3 and working on how to visualize the dfs algorithm using network graph. After some iterations of updating the states, the browser hangs and page becomes unresponsive.
I think that I may not be clearing the svg before updating but not getting exactly how to do it.

Below is the renderer code which call the **ForceGraph** function

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ForceGraph } from "../forceGraph/forceGraph";
import { Container, Row, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./renderer.css";
import data_dummy from "../../data/dummyGraph.json";
import OptionsButton from "../../components/buttons/optionsButton";
import DFS from "../../algorithms/graphTraversal/dfs";

function GraphOptionTab({
  handleStartVisualization,
  handleGenerateRandomGraph,
}) {
  return (
    <Container className="graph_option_container">
      <Row className="graph_option_container_row">
        <OptionsButton onClick={handleGenerateRandomGraph}>
          Random graph
        </OptionsButton>
        <OptionsButton onClick={handleStartVisualization}>
          Start visualization
        </OptionsButton>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
function generateRandomGraph() {
  var numberOfNodes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);

  var nodes = [];
  var links = [];

  var currentNode = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfNodes);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
    var node = {};

    node.id = i;
    nodes.push({ ...node });

    var links_for_each_node = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    for (var j = 0; j < links_for_each_node; j++) {
      var link = {};

      var source = i;
      var target = i;
      while (source === target) {
        target = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfNodes);
      }

      link.source = source;
      link.target = target;
      link.weight = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfNodes);

      links.push({ ...link });
    }
  }

  var data = {};
  data.nodes = [...nodes];
  data.links = [...links];
  return data;
}
export default function Renderer() {
  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState("graph");
  const [data, setData] = useState(generateRandomGraph());
  const [c, setC] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);

  function runAnimation() {
    if (data === null) return;
    var seq = DFS(data);
    console.log(seq);
    seq.forEach((a, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setData({ ...a });
      }, i * 1000 * 2);
    });
  }

  return renderer === "graph" ? (
    <Container className="graph_container">
      <Row className="graph_container_row1">
        <GraphOptionTab
          handleGenerateRandomGraph={() => {
            setData({ ...generateRandomGraph() });
          }}
          handleStartVisualization={() => {
            if (isRunning) {
              runAnimation();
            }
            setIsRunning(!isRunning);
          }}
        ></GraphOptionTab>
      </Row>
      <Row className="graph_container_row2">
        <ForceGraph data={data}></ForceGraph>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  ) : null;
}
```

**ForceGraph**

```
import React from "react";
import { runForceGraph } from "./forceGraphGenerator";
import styles from "./forceGraph.module.css";
export function ForceGraph({ data }) {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data != null) {
      if (containerRef.current) {
        const { svg, simulation } = runForceGraph(
          containerRef.current,
          data.links,
          data.nodes,
          data.vis,
          data.currentNode
        );

        return function cleanup(destroyFn) {
          console.log("Cleanup called");
          console.log(simulation);
          console.log(svg);
          simulation.stop();
          svg.selectAll("*").remove();
          svg.remove();
        };
      }
    }
  });

  return <div ref={containerRef} className={styles.container} />;
}
```

**ForceGraphGenerator**

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import styles from "./forceGraph.module.css";

export function runForceGraph(
  container,
  linksData,
  nodesData,
  vis,
  currentNode
) {
  const links = linksData.map((d) => Object.assign({}, d));
  const nodes = nodesData.map((d) => Object.assign({}, d));
  console.log(`hello current node = ${currentNode}`);
  const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const height = containerRect.height;
  const width = containerRect.width;

  const color = () => {
    return "#29FF29";
  };

  const icon = (d) => {
    return d.gender === "male" ? "\uf222" : "\uf221";
  };

  const getClass = (d) => {
    return d.gender === "male" ? styles.male : styles.female;
  };

  const drag = (simulation) => {
    const dragstarted = (event, d) => {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    };

    const dragged = (event, d) => {
      d.fx = event.x;
      d.fy = event.y;
    };

    const dragended = (event, d) => {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    };

    return d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);
  };

  const simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation(nodes)

    .force(
      "link",
      d3
        .forceLink(links)
        .id((d) => {
          return d.id;
        })
        .distance(200)
        .strength(1)
    )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))

    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY());

  simulation.tick(300);

  const svg = d3
    .select(container)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height]);

  const link = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 1)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value));

  const node = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 24)
    .attr("fill", (d) => {
      if (currentNode === d.id) return "#ff3b76";
      if (vis && vis[d.id]) return "#fff";
      return color();
    })

    .call(drag(simulation));

  const edge_node = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(links)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", "#fff")

    .call(drag(simulation));

  const label = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", styles.node_text)
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")

    .text((d) => {
      return d.id;
    })
    .call(drag(simulation));

  const edge_label = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", styles.edge_label)
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .text((d) => {
      return d.weight;
    })
    .call(drag(simulation));

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    //update link positions
    link
      .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

    // update node positions
    node.attr("cx", (d) => d.x).attr("cy", (d) => d.y);

    // update label positions
    label
      .attr("x", (d) => {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", (d) => {
        return d.y;
      });

    edge_node
      .attr("cx", (d) => Math.floor((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2))
      .attr("cy", (d) => Math.floor((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2));
    edge_label
      .attr("x", (d) => {
        return Math.floor((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2);
      })
      .attr("y", (d) => {
        return Math.floor((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2);
      });
  });

  return {
    simulation,
    svg,
  };
}
```

**DFS**

```
  vis[v] = true;
  var state = {};
  state.vis = [...vis];
  state.currentNode = v;
  state.nodes = data.nodes;
  state.links = data.links;
  seq.push({ ...state });
  adjList[v].forEach((i) => {
    if (!vis[i]) {
      dfsWrapper(data, adjList, vis, i, seq);
    }
  });
}
export default function DFS(data) {
  var seq = [];
  var numberOfNodes = data.nodes.length;
  var vis = new Array(numberOfNodes).fill(false);
  var adjList = new Array(numberOfNodes);

  for (var i = 0; i < adjList.length; i++) {
    adjList[i] = new Array();
  }
  console.log(data.links);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
    // console.log(data.links[i]["source"]);
    adjList[data.links[i]["source"]].push(data.links[i]["target"]);
    // console.log(adjList[data.links[i]["source"]]);
  }

  console.log(adjList);
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
    if (!vis[i]) {
      dfsWrapper(data, adjList, vis, data.nodes[i].id, seq);
    }
  }

  var state = {};
  state.vis = [...vis];
  state.currentNode = numberOfNodes + 1;
  state.nodes = data.nodes;
  state.links = data.links;
  seq.push({ ...state });
  return seq;
}
```

Hope that my question is clear and it would be very kind if anyone suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: Any other approaches for visualizing the graph algorithms are also appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you re-create you SVG element on each update of data instead of create SVG once and then update it when the data is changed

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks a lot for the suggestion. Can you please suggest the changes in code or some reference? It would be great of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split **runForceGraph** into 2 functions: **createForceGraph** and **updateForceGraph**

Call  **createForceGraph** once when you mount your component:

```
export function createForceGraph(...) {
  ...
  const svg = d3
    .select(container)
    .append("svg")
  ...
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
  ...
}
```

Call **updateForceGraph** each time the data is changed:

```
export function updateForceGraph(...) {
  ...
  const edge_label = d3
  .select('.labels')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
 ...
```